# Performance optimization: Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, query-performance, active-model-serializers

I would like to improve performance of rendered `json` generated by `ActiveModel::Serializer`. Please find below sample code:

In controller,

```
render json: Abc.where(" flag = ?",true).order('created_at DESC').map{|p| XyzSerializer.new(p)}.to_json, :callback => params['callback']
```

In AbcSerializer,

```
class AbcSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer   

attributes :attr1, :attr2, :attr3

def attr1
 store = PQR.find_by(id: object.id)
 store.name
end
def attr2
 store = PQR.find_by(id: object.id)
 store.pqr_association_tables.name
end
def attr3
  object.image.url
end
```

In XyzSerializer,

```
class XyzSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

attributes :attr1, :attr2, :attr3

def attr1
 store = DEF.find_by(id: object.id)
 store.name
end
def attr2
 store = DEF.find_by(id: object.id)
 store.created_at
end
def attr3
  store = DEF.find_by(id: object.id)
  store.updated_at
end
```

In ABC model,

```
class Abc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :xyzs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In Xyz model,

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to   :abc
end
```

I am getting expected output. But, it takes too long. For example, it is taking more `than 15 seconds to fetch 1500 records`.

I have tried `JBuilder` gem too. But which doesn't make any difference in terms of performance.

Queries on Model `DEF` is executing thrice for each object, on Model `PQR` twice for each object, may be the bottleneck.

I am using `Ruby 2.3.0 & Rails 4.2.0` with `active_model_serializers (0.10.2)`

Any pointers would be a great help.

Comment: Your problem is not the serializer, your problem is the `N+1` query problem. For each returned entry from `ABC` you run multiple other table. You need to rewrite your `ABC` query in a way that the database returns the results as values with as few queries as possible. Can you please your database table structure? And explain how `ABC`, `DEF`, `PQR` and `XYZ` are associated to each other?

Comment: You don't need to use `.map` either. `render json: @abcs, each_serializer: XyzSerializer`

Comment: @spickermann, Yeah, there was N+1 issue. I am working on rewriting ABCs code. Thank you.